# Angular Sharing between two components without HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I HAVE, 
1.topbar folder - contains html(1) and ts(1) for topbar
2.page folder - contains html(2) and ts(2) for page

**Now i have a BUTTON in html(1)**

```html
<button (click)="refresh()" class="navbar-btn btn btn-success btn-md refresh">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh
</button>
```

**Now i have a function in ts(1)**

```
refresh()
{
console.log("this is topbar html and ts");
}
```

**NOW i have a function in html(2)**

Here ,i dont want to do anything!

**NOW,i have a function in ts(2)**

```
refreshEvent(){
console.log("i want use this function in html(1) BUT HOW??")
}
```

So,As I click *button* it should call refreshEvent()

Comment: you could put the refresh part in a service and inject that service anywhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Subject from rxjs,

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    refresh() {
        this.subject.next();
    }
    onRefresh(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Component B:

```
  constractor(private myService: MyService){}
  this.$subscription = this.myService.onRefresh().subscribe(() => this.refreshEvent() );
  ngOnDestroy() {
        this.$subscription .unsubscribe();
    }
```

Component A:

```
constractor(private myService: MyService){}

refresh()
{
  //console.log("this is topbar html and ts");
 this.myService.refresh();
}
```

If they have a child-parent relationship you can use output event,
see the documentation for more info: 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction